# New resource - Banner

Tags: android, android-imageview

Below is the error i found while working with android studio. Even if I create a new resource called "banner" what must it include ? [image]

Comment: it means there is no images in drawable folder, check your drawable folder if you have image re-name it `banner` if not copy that image then paste it in drawable folder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect you copied that code from somewhere and you don't know what it does, so let me explain.

- when you use ImageView, it has an attribute called `app:srcCompat` which is responsible for holding which image you want to show with your ImageView.
- inorder to have an image to show in your ImageView, you have to add to the drawables folder.
- inorder to see what's there in your drawables folder :

1. click **view** from the menu bar at the top of the screen.
2. choose **tools windows**
3. choose **resource manager**

[image: resource manager]

- inorder to add a new image to your drawables you should simply click the '+' button that's is show in the image, or drag your image to the resource manager panel.
  [image: how to add image as drawable]
- check the images there and choose whatever you want from them using their name into the `app:srcCompat` attribute by writing `@drawable/YOUR_IMAGE_NAME`
- to learn more about drawables specifically follow this [link](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/drawables)
- to learn more about ImageViews and how to deal with graphics in android follow this [link](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics) and learn more by following all their tutorial sections for whatever you're searching for.